# Can Grafana have local scope (panel scope) of variables?

Tags: grafana

I am designing a Dashboard with some very rich features, and to make it more customizable for the monitoring team so I want to add some variables. The problem is, it makes sense to have the same name for variables across several panels.

So it would be quite convenient if I could have a variable been declared and used only for a specific panel. I would like to reuse the variable name for other panels too, so I don't want customization of variable value in one panel to affect the other panels.

Is there a way to define variables in Grafana for a specific panel?

Comment: The documentation says nothing about panels having variables https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/